# iPhone SE app bug?

Tags: bug

The StackExchange app on my iPhone (6s) keeps prompting me to join meta - which clearly I already have.

[image: meta bug]

It prompts for this whenever I attempt and up/down vote or comment.

I have tried logging out, then back on.

I have also recently done a complete restore-to-factory-defaults on my phone<sup>1</sup>, and the issue persisted.

The bug appears to only exist for meta sites, not their corresponding main sites.

Is this a known issue? Or have any of you experienced and resolved this? It’s super annoying.

---

<sup>1</sup>*The phone restore was done to clear my phone’s cache, not as an attempt to fix this issue - though I had hoped that it would.*

Comment: This question would be much better suited for the main meta. In any case, I know that SE said they weren't maintaining the iOS and Android apps anymore, so I guess you just have to accept this bug or switch to using the website on mobile.